# How can I create a smart collection that checks for absence of values in Lightroom 2?

Tags: smart-collections, lightroom-2

I started recently supplying Location metadata to my images (not geolocation, I do that in a few cases but hardly for all of them) and I thought »Hey, a smart collection that contains all images without location would be handy«. I then created one with

> Location | is |

(the text box at the end is empty – not even whitespace) for lack of something like »is empty«. But now the collection shows no images at all, although I know there are still images with no location information there.

Is there a trick I just don't know or is it impossible to create such a smart collection? I noticed that the built-in smart collection that filters photos without keywords uses an »is empty« filter which exists for keywords but not for Location.

Comment: I just tried an empty field in Lightroom 3, and it seems to be working as you & I would expect: all photos without a setting on that field are being included. Is there a chance some other setting on your collection is tripping it up?

Comment: @Craig: Lightroom 2 here. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

As we've discussed in the question comments, it's working for me as expected in Lightroom 3.

So, I guess one "answer" is "Upgrade". :-\ It's [$99](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshoplightroom/).

Comment: Which is what I spent on LR2 already too (student version). I think I just do the workaround by selecting all photos and then refine using the filter bar.